# Helper Class Error - Grouping in Aggregate

Tags: class, group-by-rollup

I don't get an error in the console, but for the below helper class but when I edit my record I get this error on save:

"Error:Apex trigger RoomTypeTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: RoomTypeTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.UnexpectedException: field 'Room_Description__c' can not be grouped in a query call: Class.AccountRoomRollups.rollupLineItems: line 26, column 1"

I understand I am grouping in an aggregate and that might not be acceptable, I know I am missing something but can't figure out what. *NOTE: This is my very first trigger!!!*

USE CASE: the trigger worked fine with just the SUM updates to account, but then I added the room description grouping because I need to also pull the Room Description field for all children when "Need image" = TRUE on the child and enter each description in one text field on the parent account (a list of all room descriptions for children that need an image).

---

```
public without sharing class AccountRoomRollups {
    public static void rollupLineItems(List<Room_Type__c> lineItems) {
        if (lineItems != null && lineItems.isEmpty() == false) {
            //Get Account Ids
            Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
       for (Room_Type__c lineItem : lineItems) {
                if (lineItem.Hotel_Account__c != null){
                accountIds.add(lineItem.Hotel_Account__c);
               }
            }

            //Get Map of Account
            Map<Id, Account> Accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c, 
                                                              Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c,
                                                              Room_Types_Count__c,Rooms_without_Images__c 
                                                              FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]);

            //Aggregate Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c
            Map<Id, Double> mappedSum = new Map<Id, Double>();
            Map<Id, Double> mappedRmTrue = new Map<Id, Double>();
            Map<Id, Double> countRm = new Map<Id, Double>();
            //List<String> Description = new List<String>();
            String Descriptionstring = '';

              AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT Hotel_Account__c, SUM(Image_Count_mapped__c) RollupAmount, 
                                           SUM(Mapped_Images_True__c) MappedTrue,
                                           SUM(Room_Type_Count__c) RCount, Room_Description__c,Needs_a_mapped_image__c
                                           FROM Room_Type__c WHERE Hotel_Account__c IN :accountIds 
                                           GROUP BY Hotel_Account__c,Room_Description__c,Needs_a_mapped_image__c];

            for (AggregateResult result : results) {
                Id parentId = (Id) result.get('Hotel_Account__c');
                Double rollupAmount = (Double) result.get('RollupAmount');
                Double mappedTrue = (Double) result.get('MappedTrue');
                Double rCount = (Double) result.get('RCount');
                mappedSum.put(parentId, rollupAmount);
                mappedRmTrue.put(parentId, mappedTrue);
                countRm.put(parentId, rCount);
                Boolean needimage = (Boolean) result.get('Needs_a_mapped_image__c');
                String roomdescription = (String) result.get('Room_Description__c');

                IF (needimage = True) {

                    Descriptionstring += roomdescription + '\n';
                    }           
            }


            //Map Amounts for Update
            List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();

            for(Id parentId : accounts.keySet()) {
                Account acc = accounts.get(parentId);

                Double rollupAmount = 0;
                Double mappedTrue = 0;
                Double rCount = 0;

                if (mappedSum.containsKey(parentId)||mappedRmTrue.containsKey(parentId)) {
                    rollupAmount = mappedSum.get(parentId);
                    mappedTrue = mappedRmTrue.get(parentId);
                    rCount = countRm.get(parentId);
                }

                if (rollupAmount != acc.Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c || mappedTrue != acc.Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c || rCount != acc.Room_Types_Count__c){
                    acc.Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c = rollupAmount;
                    acc.Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c = mappedTrue;
                    acc.Room_Types_Count__c = rCount;
                    acc.Rooms_without_Images__c = Descriptionstring;
                    accToUpdate.add(acc);
                }
            }

            //Update Account
            if (accToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
                update accToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing BarCotter -- I could not figure out how to fix that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `GROUP BY` a `Text Area` field, which it looks like `Room_Description__c` is. If you really must group by description, you may want to populate the value of this field into a plain `Text` field somewhere, or just change the type to `Text`. `Text` fields can be grouped.

Comment: Thank you Adrian! I changed the field type to plain text and Rooms_without_Images__c field updated as expected except it is not following the rule of the "IF (needimage = True)", instead it is entering all descriptions. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your continued support!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the helper class like this instead:

public without sharing class AccountRoomRollups {
    public static void rollupLineItems(List lineItems) {
        if (lineItems != null && lineItems.isEmpty() == false) {
            //Get Account Ids
            Set accountIds = new Set();

```
        for (Room_Type__c lineItem : lineItems) {
            if (lineItem.Hotel_Account__c != null){
            accountIds.add(lineItem.Hotel_Account__c);
           }
        }

        //Get Map of Account
        Map<Id, Account> Accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c, 
                                                          Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c,
                                                          Room_Types_Count__c,Rooms_without_Images__c 
                                                          FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]);

        //Aggregate Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c
        Map<Id, Double> mappedSum = new Map<Id, Double>();
        Map<Id, Double> mappedRmTrue = new Map<Id, Double>();
        Map<Id, Double> countRm = new Map<Id, Double>();
        //List<String> Description = new List<String>();
        Map<Id, String> Description = new Map<Id, String>();

        String Descriptionstring = '';
        Double rollupSum = 0;
        Double mappedTrueSum = 0;
        Double rCountSum = 0;

        for (Room_Type__c result : [SELECT Hotel_Account__c, Image_Count_mapped__c, 
                                       Mapped_Images_True__c,
                                       Room_Type_Count__c ,
                                       Room_Description__c,
                                       Needs_a_mapped_image__c
                                       FROM Room_Type__c WHERE Hotel_Account__c IN :accountIds ]) {

            Id parentId = (Id) result.get('Hotel_Account__c');

            Double rollupAmount = (Double) result.get('Image_Count_mapped__c');
                rollupSum += rollupAmount;
            Double mappedTrue = (Double) result.get('Mapped_Images_True__c');
                mappedTrueSum += mappedTrue;
            Double rCount = (Double) result.get('Room_Type_Count__c');
                rCountSum += rCount;

            mappedSum.put(parentId, rollupSum);
            mappedRmTrue.put(parentId, mappedTrueSum);
            countRm.put(parentId, rCountSum);

            Boolean needimage = (Boolean) result.get('Needs_a_mapped_image__c');
            String roomdescription = (String) result.get('Room_Description__c');

            IF (needimage == True) {
                Descriptionstring += roomdescription + '\n';
                System.debug('Descriptionstring: '+Descriptionstring);
            }
            Description.put(parentId, Descriptionstring);
        }

        //Map Amounts for Update
        List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for(Id parentId : Accounts.keySet()) {
            Account acc = Accounts.get(parentId);

            Double rollupAmount = 0;
            Double mappedTrue = 0;
            Double rCount = 0;

            if (mappedSum.containsKey(parentId)||mappedRmTrue.containsKey(parentId) || countRm.containsKey(parentId)) {
                rollupAmount = mappedSum.get(parentId);
                mappedTrue = mappedRmTrue.get(parentId);
                rCount = countRm.get(parentId);
                Descriptionstring = Description.get(parentId);

                System.debug('Rollup Amount: '+rollupAmount);
                System.debug('Mapped True: '+mappedTrue);
                System.debug('rCount: '+rCount);
                System.debug('Descriptionstring: '+Descriptionstring);

            }

            if (rollupAmount != acc.Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c || mappedTrue != acc.Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c || rCount != acc.Room_Types_Count__c){
                acc.Room_Images_Mapped_Sum__c = rollupAmount;
                acc.Rooms_with_Image_Mapped_Count__c = mappedTrue;
                acc.Room_Types_Count__c = rCount;
                acc.Rooms_without_Images__c = Descriptionstring;
                accToUpdate.add(acc);

                System.debug('Rollup Amount: '+rollupAmount);
                System.debug('Mapped True: '+mappedTrue);
                System.debug('rCount: '+rCount);
                System.debug('Descriptionstring: '+Descriptionstring);                  

            }
        }

        //Update Account
        if (accToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
            update accToUpdate;
            System.debug('accToUpdate: '+accToUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

}